# Sort files numerically in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, ls

I need to sort .flv files numerically and i was able to do it with the following command:

```
ls *\.flv | sort --version-sort -f
```

but with many files(hundreds) it's not sorting correctly.

```
ls *\.flv | sort --version-sort -f | tail -n 20
e680.flv
e681.flv
e682.flv
e683.flv
e684.flv
e685.flv
e686.flv
e687.flv
e688.flv
e689.flv
e690.flv
e691.flv
e692.flv
e693.flv
e694.flv
e695.flv
**e696.flv**
s572.flv
s602.flv
s654.flv
```

but the strange this is, if i'm ruining the command without `"*.flv"` it's working. 
*i could use just ls but i have other file types in the folder.*

```
ls | sort --version-sort -f | tail -n 20
e680.flv
e681.flv
e682.flv
e683.flv
e684.flv
e685.flv
e686.flv
e687.flv
e688.flv
e689.flv
e690.flv
e691.flv
e692.flv
e693.flv
e694.flv
e695.flv
e696.flv
```

what i've tried so far:

```
    ls | sort --version-sort -f | grep "flv"
    ls *.flv | sort --version-sort -f
    ls *\.flv | sort --version-sort -f
    ls *.flv | sort -f
```

Comment: what's the problem? `e696.flv` is in the right place, right?

Comment: did you try to simply execute "ls *.flv | sort -f | tail -n 20
"

Comment: @m1k3y3 it wouldn't work with changing number of digits in the filename

Comment: ls *.flv | sort -f skips files... i could use just ls but i have other file types in the folder.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would try following code. Works on my testing scenario:

```
ls -1 *\.flv | sort -n -k1.2
```

The `ls` lists flv files 1 on each line, `sort` takes first (and only one) word on each line starting on second character (start of the number). Sorts numerically

Answer (score 16):

Given a folder with sequentially named files from `1.flv` to `9999.flv`

```
ls -v1 *.flv
```

will output:

```
1.flv
2.flv
...
10.flv
...
90.flv
...
100.flv
101.flv
...
9999.flv
```

From the [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/ls1.html):

```
    -v     natural sort of (version) numbers within text
    -1     list one file per line
```

For brevity, the two flags above can be clubbed together as `-v1`.

Comment: It works wonders! I have been trying all types options with sort but -v1 works great. What does -v1 mean? When looking at the manpage it says "sort by version".. not sure I understood what that means. thanks.

Comment: @Molly_K: see the updated answer; `versions` are just numbers, e.g. `1.9`, `2.0`, `10.2`, and specifying `-v` forces them to be sorted numerically rather than as strings.

Answer (score 5):

to sort numerically after first character, try this :

```
sort -k1.2n
```