# How does `--key (-k)` work for command `sort`?

Tags: sorting, command-line

From the manual of the command `sort`

```
   -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
          start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
```

Versions:

- sort: `GNU coreutils 5.93`
- OS: `MAC OSX 10.11.6`
- Bash: `GNU bash 3.2.57(1)`
- Terminal: `2.6.1`

It does  not quite help me to understand how to use this option. I've seen patterns like `-k1 -k2` and `-k1,2` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033692/bash-short-by-two-columns)), `-k1.2` and `-k1.2n` (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360925/sort-files-numerically-in-bash)) and `-k3 -k1 -k4` (see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/569339/unix-command-to-sort-the-file-by-the-following-words-from-major-sort-key-to-min)).

**How does the flag `--key (-k)` work for the command `sort`?**

---

I only have a vague intuition about what can be done with the option `-k` but if it is handy to consider an example, I would be happy for you to consider numerically (`-n`) sorting the following input by the numbers that directly follow the word "row". If two records have the same value after the word "row", then sorting could be done numerically on the value that follows the letter "G".

```
H3_row24_G500.txt
H3_row32_G1000.txt
H3_row9_G999.txt
H3_row9_G1000.txt
H3_row24_G999.txt
H3_row102_G500.txt
H3_row2400_G999.txt
H3_row68_G999.txt
H3_row68_G500.txt
```

The expected output is

```
H3_row9_G999.txt
H3_row9_G1000.txt
H3_row24_G500.txt
H3_row24_G999.txt
H3_row32_G1000.txt
H3_row68_G500.txt
H3_row68_G999.txt
H3_row102_G500.txt
H3_row2400_G999.txt
```

Comment: What OS are you on and which manual are you quoting from?

Comment: @melpomene info added in the post. Thank you!

Comment: Which manual are you quoting from?

Comment: By the way, here's [the manual for GNU sort](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#sort-invocation).

Comment: @melpomene I was citing from the output of `man sort`. Your link helped a lot though! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the manpage

```
   KEYDEF is F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]] for start and stop position, where F is a field number
   and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults
   to  the  line's end.  If neither -t nor -b is in effect, characters in a field are counted
   from the beginning of the preceding whitespace.  OPTS is one or more single-letter  order‐
   ing options [bdfgiMhnRrV], which override global ordering options for that key.  If no key
   is given, use the entire line as the key.  Use --debug to diagnose incorrect key usage.
```

The implication is that sort splits lines into fields. The period separator is used to offset into the field. With `_` as your separator, you'd use an offset of 4.

In this case, the field delimiter isn't whitespace and so you would need to specify it using the `-t` option.

sort uses a locale based search by default and it looks like you want these sorted numerically. The -n switch does this.

```
sort -t _ -k 2.4 -n
```

Comment: Also `sort -V` will do this for free, without too much hassle. Note the 3d field is not sorted as OP wanted .

Answer (score 2):

The `.` specifies a starting position within a single field. You want to sort numerically on fields 2 (starting at character 4) and 3 (starting at character 2). The following should work:

```
sort -t_ -k2.4n -k3.2n tmp.txt
```

- `-t_` specifies the field separator
- The first key is `2.4n`
- The second key, if the first keys are equal, is `3.2n`

Technically, `.txt` is part of field 3, but when you ask for numeric sorting, the trailing non-digit characters are ignored.

(More correctly, `-k2.4,2n -k3.2,3n` prevents any additional fields from being included in each key; I think the simpler form shown above works because any overlap is "overwritten", as it were. `n` prevents field 3 by itself from being treated as a number, and there is no field 4.)

Comment: Shouldn't that be `-k2.4,2n -k3.2,3n`? [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#index-POSIXLY_005fCORRECT-4) cautions: "*Note that if you had written `-k 2n` instead of `-k 2,2n` `sort` would have used all characters beginning in the second field and extending to the end of the line as the primary numeric key. For the large majority of applications, treating keys spanning more than one field as numeric will not do what you expect.*"

Comment: Proooooobably. It works the same for the given input, and I think in this case, since field 3 by itself isn't a number, `-k2.4n` is effectively equivalent to `-k2.4,2n`. But the expanded form certainly isn't wrong, and could cover a corner case I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a programming question, but here goes:

If you're using GNU sort, your desired output can be achieved by `sort -V`:

```
$ echo 'H3_row24_G500.txt
H3_row32_G1000.txt
H3_row9_G999.txt
H3_row9_G1000.txt
H3_row24_G999.txt
H3_row102_G500.txt
H3_row2400_G999.txt
H3_row68_G999.txt
H3_row68_G500.txt' | sort -V
```

```
H3_row9_G999.txt
H3_row9_G1000.txt
H3_row24_G500.txt
H3_row24_G999.txt
H3_row32_G1000.txt
H3_row68_G500.txt
H3_row68_G999.txt
H3_row102_G500.txt
H3_row2400_G999.txt
```

That's because [`-V` compares numeric and general string segments separately](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Details-about-version-sort) and `H`, `3`, `_row` are the same in all lines.